# How To supress getting focus to TextBox and its form when Text Changes in C#?

Tags: c#, textbox, focus, richtextbox

I have a Form  (`Form1`) and a Rich Text Box (`RichBox1`) inside of it.

I have many objects that can append text in `RichBox1` 
and Two Other Forms (`Form2`, `Form3`)

When that happens, if the application does not have focus (say user is using a calculator) 
and when the user sets focus back to the application thru selecting `Form2`, 
`Form1` gets focus first if the `RichBox1` got new text while the user wasn't using it.

I've looked at all properties and can't find it. a .CanFocus for the textbox cannot be set to false as it can only be read. Any ideas?

Thanks

Edit:
I've Added:

`this.GotFocus += new EventHandler(Form1_GotFocus);`

This event does not fire at all.

I have a whole bunch of other controls in `Form1`, a few labels, buttons and menu strips. I do not understand what is causing this behaviour.

EDIT 2:

Perhaps can someone suggest an event to raise in `Form1` to start tracking what is causing this. I am assuming it has to do with `RichBox1` but not so sure now.

EDIT 3.

Added:
`this.Activated += new EventHandler(Form1_GotFocus);`

This event does not fire when I do the above. Perhaps this means that `Form2` loses focus, instead of `Form1` getting activated? Also worth noting this behaviour appears when I right click in `Form2`

Comment: Is that for winforms or WPF?

Comment: Generic tip: Instead of using phrases such as "some other form", "original form", etc, name the particles of your problem with a simple 1, 2, 3 and show how things go step by step, as in a list, line by line, and then the same for how things should go.

Comment: Show some code for starters.. are any of the forms Modal forms..?

Comment: What other controls are on your Form with the RichTextBox

Comment: @DJKRAZE not sure what code more to add. The Forms have lots of code inside them. Perhaps suggest an event to look into when the form does get focus and track what is causing it?

Comment: Why the downvotes so quick? such happy trigger fingers. I've updated it, sry not a usual user of forums, got stuck looking for help

Comment: @MarkHall: 1 MenuStrip (with 5 menus), one textbox (accessible only from `Form1`, one button, and 'RichBox1'

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Form Activated event. Though I made a small test case and I can not duplicate your problem, if the RichTextBox's Text Changes I can still select Form2, make sure you do not have a timer or event setting focus to the RichTextBox

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Activated += new EventHandler(Form1_Activated);  
}

void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Set the Focus to the Control that you want
    button1.Focus();
}
```